# Mbstring extension missing phpmyadmin

Tags: 16.04, phpmyadmin

As I have seen many questions already about the mbstring extention missing, I have the same and I tried all the answers given on the other questions...

> sudo apt-get install php-gettext
>   sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

(all of the commands worked fine btw)
etc etc... and none of them work...

I have ubuntu 16.04 running on a Vmware virtual machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that `extension=mbstring` and `extension=php_mysqli` on `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` is not commented.

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: You still have to *install* those components, and with OP using 16.04 from 6 years ago (that's how old this post is) it's unlikely this will solve their issues.